# Filter notifications within policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

Whenever a model is created (or deleted/modified) every connected socket is notified through Sails autowatch setting. That's fine to some extent, but I'd like to filter these notifications at some point.

My application has its own "Notifications" which should be sent to their respective receiver. So their anatomy is somewhat like: `id, message, receiver, sender`.

Authentication is a local passport implementation.

Listening for `notification` events result in getting notified every time a notification is created.

```
// client: app.js
io.socket.on('notification', function(evt) { console.log(evt); });
```

What I try to achieve now is to filter these notifications to match the user id. I've written a policy which gets applied to the `/notification` events.

```
// Policy: forUser
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // ... whatever ... //

  return next();
}
```

Within the policies

```
  'notification': {
    'create': ['passport', 'forUser']
  }
```

My problem now is: how to implement this policy? I thought of just checking for `notification.receiver == req.user.id`, but how to get the notification model within the policy (if this is the right way at all)?

Thanks.

**Edit**: Tried implementing the room solution, but I don't get any notifications on the client.

I've altered my subscribe function within my NotificationController:

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
        sails.log.info('Your user id: ' + req.user.id);
        sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'user_notifications_' + req.user.id);
        res.json({
            room: 'user_notifications_' + req.user.id
        });
    },
```

And added a `afterCreate` method to my model:

```
afterCreate: function(model, next) {
    sails.sockets.broadcast('user_notifications_' + model.receiver, { test: 'hello' });
    next();
  }
```

Code on client is now:

```
  io.socket.get("/notification/subscribe", function(data, jwr) {
    io.socket.on(data.room, function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);
    });
  });
```

The subscription method is called and returns the right room name. But I don't get any messages when calling `/notification/create?message=test&receiver=1`. The `afterCreate` method is called, all user ids are right (since there's only one user), but nothing happens.

Edit2:
It seems like joining the rooms fails.

```
sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'testroom');
// For testing
sails.log.debug(sails.sockets.socketRooms(req.socket));
```

The room gets created, but the socket is not subscribed to it.

Edit3:
**Found the solution. I'll post the GitHub link as soon as the interface is done.**

Comment: Do you want this policy to filter the outgoing websocket messages ? The policies are not applied to *events* but to *controllers*. They cannot control what happen when socket.io is emitting messages to clients. Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: No, that's right. I want to filter outgoing socket messages. If policies aren't capable of doing this, what's the right way of filtering socket messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `sails.sockets.blast()` to send your notifications?

To send custom events, you could use [sails.sockets.emit()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/sails-sockets-emit)

```
// Controller action
actionSendingNotification: function(req, res) {
  // Retrieve the user socket ID and the data to send
  // ...
  sails.sockets.emit(userSocketId, 'notification', data);
}
```

You have to be able to know if the user has an active websocket connection and retrieve his socket ID. He could have several tabs opened in his browser and several websocket connections ...

A probably better solution would be to use [sails.sockets.join()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/sails-sockets-join) and [sails.sockets.broadcast()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/sails-sockets-broadcast). You would then create the association between the *connected user* and the *observed event* within `socket.io`.

```
// When the user creates a websocket connection, subscribe him to the model room
// This action MUST be called by a websocket request
// Here I assume your event is related to a model
subscribeToModelRoom: function(req, res) {
  var roomName = 'myModelRoom' + req.param('model_id');
  sails.sockets.join(req.socket, roomName);
  res.json({
    message: 'Subscribed to a room called '+roomName+'!'
  });
}
```

Then every time you send a message to the room, the subscribed user will receive it.

```
// When the model has to send a notification, use broadcast() to send it to the room associated to the model.
sails.sockets.broadcast('myModelRoom' + modelInstance.id, 'notification', data);
```

---

**Edit**
Reading your question again, I will add some explanations.

It seems that you try to send your notification to a user, based on his `user.id`. You cannot assume that this user will be connected via websocket when you send this notification. **You don't send events to a user, but to a opened websocket connection** (that may be authenticated).

If the user must not miss the notification, you have to store it in a database. You will then show it to the user when he will be connected.

If you want the user to be informed in real time while he is connected, you could subscribe him to a room `"user_notifications_" + user.id` when you initialize his authenticated websocket connection. Then emit an event to this room when you create a new notification.

You could add the logic to manage *seen / not seen* notifications and delete the obsolete records.

This way, you can send information to your users in real time and you will not lose the information if nobody is here to receive it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Modified my application and played around with the rooms, but I still don't get any notifications. I've edited the entry post and added my changes.

Comment: Glad you get it working! Could you accept the answer if it helped you?